Error when evaluating SSR module /opt/buildhome/repo/astro.config.ts: failed to import "astro-icon"
I have been successful with building an Astro based website by deploying through Cloudflare pages. Since this morning I am getting the following error when building the website. I thought of updating "astro-icon" package to its latest version, however, it is already the latest version.
Here is the error message:
00:22:10.397    4:22:10 AM [vite] Error when evaluating SSR module /opt/buildhome/repo/astro.config.ts: failed to import "astro-icon"

00:22:10.398    |- file:///opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/.pnpm/@iconify+tools@3.0.7/node_modules/@iconify/tools/lib/svg/index.mjs:1

00:22:10.398    import cheerio from 'cheerio';

00:22:10.398    SyntaxError: The requested module 'cheerio' does not provide an export named 'default'

00:22:10.399        at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:124:21)

00:22:10.399        at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:190:5)

00:22:10.399    [astro] Unable to load your Astro config
    
00:22:10.727    The requested module 'cheerio' does not provide an export named 'default'

00:22:10.727      Stack trace:

00:22:10.727        at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:124:21)

00:22:10.863    Failed: Error while executing user command. Exited with error code: 1

00:22:10.872    Failed: build command exited with code: 1

00:22:11.796    Failed: error occurred while running build command 


Here is what worked for me per the link that @oceanhhan shared below. I included "resolutions": {     "cheerio": "1.0.0-rc.12"    } to package.json file and now the repo can be built via Cloudflare pages.

I was facing the same issue today, and after trying to upgrade, downgrade etc .. the only solution I found is to monkey patch the iconify package to resolve the issue.
As you can see , the file having the import error is : node_modules/.pnpm/@iconify+tools@3.0.7/node_modules/@iconify/tools/lib/svg/index.mjs:1
I changed the very first line :
import cheerio from 'cheerio';

to
import * as cheerio from 'cheerio';

Now the project is building properly. Hope this will help.

Salem, I added your suggestion to 'astro.config.ts' file but it did not work. did you mean some other file?

the change should be me made to this file inside node modules in iconify package (where error is happening): node_modules/.pnpm/@iconify+tools@3.0.7/node_modules/@iconify/tools/lib/svg/index.mjs:1  NOTICE : this will only resolve in local build however not on remote build . I'll get back with a solution when I find one.

Thanks, Salem. It would be great if you can find a solution for remote build. I only have access to my Git repository (not Cloudflare node modules), so if the solution that can be implemented through Git repository files would be awesome!

I also started to encounter the same error as you from today, which almost drives me crazy. On vercel it was packaged and built as normal, but the local kept reporting errors, even after I cleared pnpm's cache.

This issue will also be helpful: https://github.com/natemoo-re/astro-icon/issues/231

Thank you. That link had the solutions to be implemented through package.json file or pnpm, or npm methods.

The solution is installing npm install @iconify/tools --save

Where on Cloudflare did you add "npm install @iconify/tools --save"

add this to package.json:
{
      "dependencies": {
        "astro-icon": "^1.1.0"
      },
      "pnpm": {
        "overrides": {
          "@iconify/tools": "^4.0.4"
        }
      }
    }

